# A newly created user is unable to access sound devices

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, user-management

I have created a new user, went to user groups and checked 'use audio devices'. However, when i log into that user account i see that no sound can be played.

When i go to audio mixer it says that it is unable to connect to pulse-audio server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xfce4-session-settings
```

[image]

Control, if pulseaudio is starting with session. If not add it.